# 逃げる vs 逃す. What's the nuance?

Tags: nuances

It's pretty straightforward, I'm wondering what the nuance between 逃げる and 逃す is?

I'm assuming it's something like the difference between "run away" and "escape", but which one is which?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

逃げる（にげる）→ escape

逃す（のがす）→ let escape (tried to catch it but could not)

逃がす（にがす）→ let escape (on purpose)

Comment: Oh, thank you man, I actually had a whole other question lined up, but my copy and past skills (and brain skills) are not up to snuff today :)

Comment: I always think of 逃す in connection with 見逃す, as in 敵を見逃さないで！！