# 逃げる vs 逃れる What's the nuance?

Tags: nuances

This is the question I was trying to ask when I made [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11929/%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B%E3%80%80vs%E3%80%80%E9%80%83%E3%81%99%E3%80%80whats-the-nuance), but I guess I can't type or read or think.

I'm looking for the difference between `逃げる` and `逃れる`. I'm assuming it's something like the difference between "run away" and "escape", but which one is which?

And I'm aware that even "run away" and "escape" are pretty close even in English, but these things happen.

Comment: There's a [usage note on 大辞泉](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=0&dtype=0&p=%E9%80%83%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B) (scroll down to the bottom).

Comment: This may be some help too? http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/1604/m0u/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They both mean to "run away" or "escape", but `逃げる` means this only physically while `逃れる` means this physically or metaphorically (escape a bad situation, run from temptation, avoid responsibility, etc.)

Comment: "逃げる" often has more negative sense, especially when used in non-physical situations, while "逃れる" is more neutral. For example, 「彼はその仕事から逃げた」 usually implies he was not a serious worker. 「彼はその仕事から逃れた」 may mean he had a good reason for quitting the job.